# UnusedResources in lint gives wrong results

Tags: android, performance, android-lint

I have a project which includes one main project and 6 library project. I want to find out the unused resources in all the 7 modules using lint.
I have tried running the following command

lint --check UnusedResources --html report.html foldername

I have run this individually in each module and also on the parent folder which contains all the 7 modules

Now the report.html shows list of resources which are unused. I am facing 2 issues with this list

1) It includes lots of resources from layout folder which are being used in the project but it shows them as unused. Similarly with strings and dimensions.

2) It does not include any png from drawables. Although there are some png files which are not being used.

Can somebody please tell where am i going wrong in this?

Comment: those pngs are not used at all? or are they used in other unused drawable?

Comment: Some of the pngs are not used at all. Since the code uses some open source components, so there are hundreds of pngs, out of which some are not used at all.